# which link will put in admob for non play apps

Tags: android

Hi I have created some non-play apps now I want to integrate ad mob's banner and interstitial ads in it
but my problem is which link i provide when we create new app in ad mob.I have search it but can't find any proper solution.I have also go through ad mob.so,how to use ad mob's ads for non-play apps.please help me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For older version of Admob,
In the URL, add your application package name.

For example your package name is com.example.abc

Then you'll add

```
market://details?id=<com.example.abc>
```

It doesn't matter that if your app is on play store or not. Mine is not and it worked fine.

Comment: no you didn't get my question.what should be their in Android Package URL when creating new app on admob if my app is not on google play store

Comment: please notice that i am asking it for older admob